# 4-20ma current loop and ESP32

Tags: adc, current-measurement, esp32, 4-20ma

Following a previous question I'm thinking of using the following design for a 4-20ma 24VDC preasure sensor with an ESP32 ADC pin

[image]

- Will it actually work?
- Should I add aditional protection like two diodes on OUT?
- If the sensor is powered by 24VDC and the LM358 is powerd by 5VDC is it possible to get a voltage over 3.3V on OUT in case of sensor malfunction?

Comment: Not sure why you would involve op amps at all (and if you do, shouldn't they be rail-to-rail)? You could just use two diodes (towards + and GND), a voltage divider and a shunt resistor.

Comment: The ESP32 ADC has some issues. You might want to consider using an external adc. As Lundin suggests, you don't really need an opamp - just a sense resistor and protection.

Comment: @jasen. I understand what you want to do. I've done plenty of 4-20mA. Is your sensor a two wire or three wire device?

Comment: it's a two wire device

Comment: @Marc. It's a loop powered device then. Even though the op-amp gives you a differential input, you're still constrained by the common-mode range of the op-amp. Also, since you're using a single rail op-amp, you need a virtual earth as the output cannot swing below gnd. The output swing of the LM358 is also constrained - read the datasheet. If you tie the gnd of the 24VDC supply to the ESP32 gnd. Using a 100R sense resistor gives you 2V @ 20mA. You can adjust this value depending of the span of the ADC. 24VDC goes to the sensor +, sensor - goes to the top of the sense resistor.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a 150 ohm 1% resistor to ground and leave out the rest.

The Expressif chip has about a 1V input range, but the boards typically have divider resistors so the range is actually about 3V (maybe nominally 3.3, but you can't count on that due to reference tolerance and resistor tolerance) because of an internal divider.

The ADC has **appallingly**-bad characteristics (linearity, stability, noise, tolerance) and is only worthwhile because of the price (which is zero). You should research this before going any further down this path.

Tying it to any decent 4~20mA transmitter is probably a gross mismatch, suggest you look at using an external ADC.